# sharing ebpf function parameters with usespace or atleast accessing parameters

Tags: c, linux, parameters, ebpf

I have this ebpf program that I am trying to do. Basically, I am trapping `recvfrom` function call and trying to share my `recvfrom` buffer to my userspace application. This is the code:

```
SEC("kprobe/__x64_sys_recvfrom")
int bpf_prog1(struct pt_regs *ctx,int fd, const char *buf, size_t count)
{
    struct S {
        int pid;
        char cookie[90];
    } data={1,""};

    //data.pid =count;// bpf_get_current_pid_tgid();
    //if(buf==NULL)
//  memcpy(data.cookie,buf,20);
    
 //       data.cookie[0]=buf[0];
        
        bpf_get_current_comm(&data.cookie, sizeof(data.cookie));
        int i=0;

    bpf_perf_event_output(ctx, &my_map, 1, &data, sizeof(data));
    
    return 0;
}
```

So, it seems like I have signature of `bpf_prog function` and in it, I have buffer from `recvfrom` function but when I try to access it, I simply can't because my program is loading complains.

```
root@this:/home/ubuntu/Desktop/ebpf/Linux-exFilter-main/pkg/probe/bpf# ./trace
libbpf: load bpf program failed: Permission denied
libbpf: -- BEGIN DUMP LOG ---
libbpf: 
R1 type=ctx expected=fp
; int bpf_prog1(struct pt_regs *ctx,int fd, const char *buf, size_t count)
0: (bf) r6 = r1
1: (b7) r1 = 0
; } data={1,""};
2: (7b) *(u64 *)(r10 -8) = r1
last_idx 2 first_idx 0
regs=2 stack=0 before 1: (b7) r1 = 0
3: (7b) *(u64 *)(r10 -16) = r1
4: (7b) *(u64 *)(r10 -24) = r1
5: (7b) *(u64 *)(r10 -32) = r1
6: (7b) *(u64 *)(r10 -40) = r1
7: (7b) *(u64 *)(r10 -48) = r1
8: (7b) *(u64 *)(r10 -56) = r1
9: (7b) *(u64 *)(r10 -64) = r1
10: (7b) *(u64 *)(r10 -72) = r1
11: (b7) r1 = 1
12: (63) *(u32 *)(r10 -96) = r1
; memcpy(data.cookie,buf,20);
13: (71) r4 = *(u8 *)(r3 +1)
R3 !read_ok
processed 14 insns (limit 1000000) max_states_per_insn 0 total_states 0 peak_states 0 mark_read 0

libbpf: -- END LOG --
libbpf: failed to load program 'bpf_prog1'
libbpf: failed to load object './kprobe_send.o'
ERROR: loading BPF object file failed
```

And there is a function like `bpf_get_current_comm(&data.cookie, sizeof(data.cookie));` and `bpf_perf_event_output(ctx, &my_map, 1, &data, sizeof(data));` and use of these functions giving me garbage data. So I like to know how to read the function parameters in ebpf programs. Is there any conventional way of doing it

I know ebpf is having maps and maps are to share info between ebpf program and userspace application. Sharing parameters  is a basic thing but I dont know why I haven't seen it on the internet

Comment: `And there is a function like bpf_get_current_comm(&data.cookie, sizeof(data.cookie)); and bpf_perf_event_output(ctx, &my_map, 1, &data, sizeof(data)); and use of these functions giving me garbage data`

Comment: accessing buf is out because accessing buf code .o does not load

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can read the parameters of `recvfrom` by using the [PT_REGS_PARM macros](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/5bfc75d92efd494db37f5c4c173d3639d4772966/tools/lib/bpf/bpf_tracing.h), in this case `PT_REGS_PARM2(ctx)`. This is an example from the [tracex4](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/9eaa88c7036eda3f6c215f87ca693594cf90559b/samples/bpf/tracex4_kern.c) sample:

```c
SEC("kprobe/kmem_cache_free")
int bpf_prog1(struct pt_regs *ctx)
{
    long ptr = PT_REGS_PARM2(ctx);

    bpf_map_delete_elem(&my_map, &ptr);
    return 0;
}
```

In the case of `recvfrom`, the second param should be a pointer to the buffer:

```
ssize_t recvfrom(int sockfd, void *buf, size_t len, int flags,
                        struct sockaddr *src_addr, socklen_t *addrlen);
```

---

To communicate from kernel to userspace you indeed need a map. You will notice that your call to `bpf_perf_event_output` also takes a pointer to a map: `&my_map`.

The `bpf_perf_event_output` helper function requires a map of type `BPF_MAP_TYPE_PERF_EVENT_ARRAY` to function. But unlike most map types this map type works like a uni-directional stream of data from the eBPF program to the userspace.

I believe your code is loosly based on the [trace_output_kern](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/5bfc75d92efd494db37f5c4c173d3639d4772966/samples/bpf/trace_output_kern.c) sample in the kernel. You will notice they define a map here as well:

```
struct {
    __uint(type, BPF_MAP_TYPE_PERF_EVENT_ARRAY);
    __uint(key_size, sizeof(int));
    __uint(value_size, sizeof(u32));
    __uint(max_entries, 2);
} my_map SEC(".maps");
```

Comment: Should this line `long ptr = PT_REGS_PARM2(ctx);` be changed to `char *ptr = PT_REGS_PARM2(ctx);` in case of recvfrom function.  Since second parameter to recvfrom is char *buf. And not long. Can u please tell

Comment: `libbpf: failed to find BTF for extern 'PT_REGS_PARM2': -2` I am getting error

Comment: `libbpf: failed to find BTF for extern 'PT_REGS_PARM2': -2` this function exists in my systems /usr/include/bpf/tracing.h` file.But running my userspace program throw this error tht it failed 2 find PT_REGS_PARM2 function. why is that.On  this link it says its problem with some ubuntu symlink and `Missing header error while trying to run a trace #76 ` whats `trace` in `Missing header error while trying to run...` https://github.com/iovisor/kubectl-trace/issues/76 .. any idea,  ever since I started looking into ebpf these error are appearing more and more as I compile samples from kernel source

Comment: `ever since I started looking into ebpf these error are appearing more and more as I compile samples from..` I have libbpf and I have kernel header but why my `clang -target -bpf` command not linking these libbpf functions to my programs that I compile and link with command `clang -O2 -Wall -g -target bpf -c kprobe_send.c -o kprobe_send.o` I know i am missing something big that stoping me compile and run ebpf program with libbpf functions. and I made sure I do have libbpf.  so is there some symlink I need to be aware of that clang uses when compiling and linking `clang -target bpf` programs.

Comment: my kernel is 5.14.1 but linux headers are 5.11.41 becuase there are no headers with apt-get install for my kernel version 5.14.1 and I did not included while installing and compiling kernel my headers  in /usr/src directory for version 5.14.1

Comment: if I include bpf/tracing.h where PT_REGS_PARM2 exists error appear in clang command that can not find bpf/tracing.h `root@this:/home/ubuntu/Desktop/ebpf/Linux-exFilter-main/pkg/probe/bpf# clang -O2 -Wall -g -target bpf -c kprobe_send.c -o kprobe_send.o
kprobe_send.c:10:10: fatal error: 'bpf/tracing.h' file not found
#include <bpf/tracing.h>
         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
1 error generated.
root@this:/home/ubuntu/Desktop/ebpf/Linux-exFilter-main/pkg/probe/bpf#`

Comment: It seems that the `libbpf: failed to find BTF for extern 'PT_REGS_PARM2': -2` is caused if an older version of libbpf is used on newer kernels. Start by getting the latest libbpf https://github.com/libbpf/libbpf, not versions available via package managers.

Comment: If you are not doing so already, you can clone the whole libbpf repo into your project as a library. It includes all files your need including the bpf/tracing.h: https://github.com/libbpf/libbpf/blob/master/src/bpf_tracing.h

Comment: is there a way to find libbpf version installed on my system ?  I have installed libbpf from github.com/libbpf/libbpf I hope direct download of zip downloads lastet version

Comment: You can likely check the version in your package manager, `sudo apt list --installed |
 grep bpf` should return something (I am not sure what the package name on ubuntu is)

Comment: `WARNING: apt does not have a stable CLI interface. Use with caution in scripts.
bpfcc-tools/hirsute,hirsute,now 0.18.0+ds-2 all [installed]libbpf-dev/hirsute,now 1:0.3-2ubuntu1 amd64 [installed]libbpf0/hirsute,now 1:0.3-2ubuntu1 amd64 [installed,automatic]libbpfcc-dev/hirsute,now 0.18.0+ds-2 amd64 [installed]
libbpfcc/hirsute,now 0.18.0+ds-2 amd64 [installed,automatic]
libpfm4/hirsute,now 4.11.1+git8-gc96ebc0-1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
python3-bpfcc/hirsute,hirsute,now 0.18.0+ds-2 all [installed,automatic]
root@this:/home/ubuntu/Desktop/ebpf/Linux-exFilter-main/pkg/probe/bpf#`

Comment: above  this what  was installed on my system and same what `sudo apt list` shows after I reinstall from the link u sent

Comment: ok now it saying `kprobe_send.c:53:22: error: Must specify a BPF target arch via __TARGET_ARCH_xxx
        char *ptr =     PT_REGS_PARM2(ctx);` what this even mean

Comment: I am on x86-64 what in my code I  should define  __TARGET_ARCH_xxx as which value? should I define it as `#define __TARGET_ARCH_xxx "x86-64"` in my ebpf program

Comment: You can specify it by adding `-D__TARGET_ARCH_x86` to your clang command when compiling

Comment: Yes it worked thanks also Should this line `long ptr = PT_REGS_PARM2(ctx);` be changed to `char *ptr = PT_REGS_PARM2(ctx)`; in case of recvfrom function. Since second parameter to recvfrom is char *buf. And not long. Can u please tell. When I do `char *ptr = PT_REGS_PARM2(ctx)`;  I get null in my userspace program. Any idea. I am using Brower  to fetch pages and my recvfrom is getting called as I use browser but ptr is printing null in userspace. Any idea

Comment: Well yes and no. You indeed get a pointer, which you can log as a long(address). But you can't use it to access the buffer directly, eBPF programs are not allowed to read kernel memory directly, you need to use the `bpf_probe_read_kernel` helper to actually read the contents of the buffer. [tracex5.c](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/samples/bpf/tracex5_kern.c) is a good example. Also keep in mind that the amount of memory you can use in an eBPF program is limited, you might not be able to read the whole buffer at once.

Comment: do u know how to extract buffer parameter for _sys_write?